# .wrap not being wrapped

Tags: jquery

I wrote this:

```
   <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script> jQuery(document).ready(function($)
     { $("div.productInfo").wrap("<div id='productDetails' />"); 
            $("ul.productInfo").wrap("<div id='specs' />");
      $("#centerColumn" + "#rightColumn").wrap("<div id='test' />");
     });
     </script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="centerColumn" >This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p id="rightColumn" >This is another paragraph.</p>
    <div class="productInfo" > Wow </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And the #centerColumn doesn't get wrapped only the #rightColumn get's wrapped, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("div.productInfo")
                .wrap("<div id='productDetails'><div id='specs' /></div>");
            $("#centerColumn, #rightColumn").wrapAll("<div id='test' />");
            // or .wrap() instead of .wrapAll() depends on your intentions
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="centerColumn">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p id="rightColumn">This is another paragraph.</p>
    <div class="productInfo"> Wow </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See also:

- [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) at jQuery API
- [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll) at jQuery API
- [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) at jQuery Docs

Answer (score 3):

You're using this selector:

```
$("#centerColumn" + "#rightColumn")
```

The `+` there is the concatenation operator. It joins the strings, so your code is the same as this:

```
$("#centerColumn#rightColumn")
```

This will obviously find nothing useful.

I think you want the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#centerColumn, #rightColumn").wrap("<div id='test' />");
```

If you want to wrap both columns in the *same* ancestor element, you'll need [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll). This seems likely because you are giving your wrapping element an `id` and `id` attributes must be unique.

```
$("#centerColumn, #rightColumn").wrapAll("<div id='test' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because this:

```
$("#centerColumn" + "#rightColumn").wrap("<div id='test' />");
```

Should be this:

```
$("#centerColumn,#rightColumn").wrap("<div id='test' />");
```